# What is the difference between [Dictionary<String, String>()] and [String: String]()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dictionary

May I know the difference between these two declaration of Dictionaries?

```
var places = [String: String]()

var places = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

Why only the second way of declaration works when I try to append it this way:

```
places.append(["name":"Taj Mahal", "lat":"27.175277", "lon":"78.042128"])
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the second one is not correct syntax, if you don't like to declare Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple dictionary:

```
var places = [String: String]()
```

Clearly, an attempt to call `append` on a dictionary won't work.

Your second rendition, though, is an array with one object, an empty dictionary:

```
var places = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

Thus, your attempt to `append` a dictionary (which had three keys, `name`, `lat`, and `long`), would work with this rendition. But I don't think this is what you intended, because that array now has two items, the original empty dictionary and the new dictionary you just added.

I suspect you really wanted an empty array of dictionaries, namely either:

```
var places = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
```

Or, more simply:

```
var places = [[String: String]]()
```

Even better, I might define a `Place` type:

```
struct Place {
    let name: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}
```

And then define `places` as an array of that type:

```
var places = [Place]()
```

And then insert a place like so:

```
places.append(Place(name: "Taj Mahal", latitude: 27.175277, longitude: 78.042128))
```

You could obviously define `Place` where `latitude` and `longitude` were strings, too, if you wanted. Whatever is appropriate of your app.